# How can I encourage members of a small organization to contribute to a wiki?

Tags: user-engagement, site-culture, wiki

I am the web site administrator for a local ham radio club. Our old site was in a blog format, and only one active member of the club did anything with it. Almost two years ago, I set up a new wiki-based site as a test, and we later decided to make it our main site. It is set up to require an account to edit; we create accounts for any member who wants one. The goal is for as many club members as possible to add content; that way, the responsibility is shared among several people.

The problem is that nobody edits except me. I'm not sure what the exact ratio is, but the vast majority of edits on the site are mine. How can I encourage more people to edit the site?

I've already tried asking people if they want accounts. Most people say yes, so I create their accounts, then they never use them. I also tried writing out note cards with ideas for articles to write, setting those cards out at a meeting, and asking people to take any they might be interested in; one person took one card, but I don't think he ever wrote anything about it on the site.

I don't think the reason is that people are afraid of making mistakes. I've explained at length that it is very easy to fix bad edits, so I doubt that's the issue.

Most of our active members were at the meeting where we passed a resolution to "create a wiki account with full editing privileges for any member who requests one" and "encourage all members to make use of these privileges by contributing to the site, even if these contributions may need further improvements." Almost everyone, if not everyone, at that meeting voted in favor of that resolution, so I believe they do know that they have these privileges.

How can I encourage club members to start editing the web site?

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem.  I've found that introducing new members to the site in person helps enormously.
Sit beside them and talk them through their first edit.

They soon become confident and start making contributions.  Also, they start to help others.

It was a slow process to get the ball rolling and I felt it might never happen, but in time it worked.